# What does 血路 mean in this passage? Is it actually Blood Road?

Tags: translation

What does 血路 mean in this passage?

From [here:](http://vocaloidlyrics.wikia.com/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%83%8E%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89_(Paranoid))

> 照らし出す血路に　指先を絡めてく
>
> Terashidasu ketsuro ni yubisaki wo karameteku
>
> In the shining path out, we entwine our fingers

Did the translation just remove the 血 and translate only 路?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal meaning is indeed "blood road".  However, this term is used idiomatically.

Per the etymology note in Shogakukan's 国語大辞典{こくごだいじてん} entry:

> （狩場で、傷ついた獣が血をたらしながら逃げる道の意から）
>     (In hunting, from the way an injured beast will leave drops of blood along its escape route)

So in usage, this term refers more metaphorically to "escape route away from an enemy".